# Elasticsearch does not keep logs

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am having couple of the strange issues with the elasticsearch:
1) When I run my web app as localhost, I get the logs in ES. But when I run the app using my public IP/domain name, then I dont get any logs. I guess this is because ES needs some settings to be changed from localhost to some IP (public or private?)
I tried several options: network.bind_host, network.publish_host, network.host - setting them to public IP and then to the private IP - it did not help.
So I am a kinda stucked. Please advise.
2) I also tried to send the logs to the remote server and it did not work. I can't even access the remote server via: public_IP:9200
Neither I can't access kibana via: public_ip:5601
I tried several options:
I set up 
network.bind_host, network.publish_host, network.host
to public ips, private ips, 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1, nothing helped.
Please advise.
Just in case, I am not sure if it's relative or not, I am using basic license for ES.

Comment: Try to open 5601 port in your server